# Can I show pageviews associated with events in custom report?

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a custom report in Google Analytics with event dimensions and pageviews as one of the metrics. View screenshot here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9WPl.jpg

My question is, will this accurately track pageviews associated with each specific event? Does GA detect the event gtag in the DOM and register 1 pageview with that specific event?

Here's my code in DOM:

```
jQuery('#unique-ad-slug').on('click', function() {

    gtag('event', 'Click', {
      'event_category': 'Ads',
      'event_label': 'Title of unique ad'
    });

});
```

Basically I'm trying to track impressions for each unique ad. I realize there are other ways to do this, but I'm wondering if this custom report will accurately reflect 1 pageview for each event when an event tag is present.

(Note: The "Events CTR" metric shown in screenshot is a custom metric that I created that divides Total Events by Pageviews.)

Answer (score 0):

No, the pageview metric in this case will be the sum of total pageviews of sessions with that event. Won't be an accurate value at all.

You will need to do it in two report tabs. One for event and total clicks and one for page and pageviews.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That makes more sense. So let's say I create two events, 1. Impression (when ad is loaded) 2. Click (when ad is clicked), could I somehow divide the Click events by the Impression events for each unique Event Category > Label?